# Mercurial - How to push current changeset to default branch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, mercurialeclipse

I'm not sure why this is so hard to figure out or google, but I am trying to take changes I made to a private branch and push them to the default branch.

In other words:

1. I pulled from the default branch a few weeks back and made major changes
2. Since then, I have finished my work
3. I then merged the code from the original default branch (just the code, the HG is still set to the "NewBranch"
4. Now that the code works, I want to commit and push these changes back to the default branch and continue my development from there.

But I can't find any information on how to do that. If I switch branches, I lose all my changesets since I am still in the NewBranch. I can't figure out what rebase or transplant do and can't find guides that explain scenarios on what they could be used for... So hopefully someone here knows what to do!

I am specifically using Mercurial on Eclipse but I am fine doing this on command line if its easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge` is the way to get changes from one branch into another. I know you merged `default` into feature, but now you go the other way.  Here's an example where numbered changesets come from other people and lettered changesets comes from you:

Before you do anything you clone and have this:

```
[1]---[2]---[3]---[4]   (default branch)
```

then you create your branch named 'feature' and do two commits on it, yielding:

```
[1]---[2]---[3]---[4]           (default branch)
                    \
                     [A]---[B]  ('feature' branch)
```

then you `hg pull` to get changes to default since you diverged down in your local repository:

```
[1]---[2]---[3]---[4]---[5]---[6]  (default branch)
                    \
                     [A]---[B]     ('feature' branch)
```

now you want their changes (5 and 6) integrated into your branch so you do:

```
hg checkout feature   # make sure you're looking at the he head of your branch
hg merge default      # merge default into your branch
```

which yields:

```
[1]---[2]---[3]---[4]---[5]---[6]        (default branch)
                    \           \
                     [A]---[B]---[C]     ('feature' branch)
```

If I'm understanding correctly, you've already done all that, so now you just need to bring your branch, including the new merge commit, C, into default, which again is done via a merge:

```
hg checkout default   # hop back to default, files look like [6] and [A] and [B] are missing
hg merge feature      # merge feature into default brining [A] and [B] in
```

that yields:

```
[1]---[2]---[3]---[4]---[5]---[6]---[7]   (default branch)
                    \           \   /
                     [A]---[B]---[C]      ('feature' branch)
```

That looks like a lot of work drawn out that way, but in practice it's usually just:

```
hg branch feature
....work....
hg commit
hg pull
hg merge default
hg checkout default
hg merge feature
```

and if the `pull` didn't bring down any new work from other you can skip the merging of default into yours.

That does create two new merge changesets.  They're easily hidden on `hg log` if you find them  unhelpful (some people love having a record of which direction each merge went), but if you want to avoid them entirely you can use `bookmarks` (very similar to git branches) instead of "named branches" for your features -- then you'll avoid a merge changeset when coming back since it would be the spiritual equivalent of what git calls a "fast forward" merge.

Comment: Ah Of course! I just need to merge in the other direction now and push. Bah! :)